# cv::imwrite "undefined" when using OpenCV 3.2

Tags: c++, opencv

I am using OpenCV 3.2.0 on Ubuntu 64-bit and have the written following code which I call WebImageIO.cpp

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <string.h>
 #include "cv.h"
 #include "highgui.h"
 #include <opencv2/core.hpp>
 #include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
 #include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>
 #include <opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp>
 #include <opencv2/videoio.hpp>
 #include <math.h>
 #include <windows.h>
 #include "Generic.h"
 #include "Palette.h"
 #include "CWebImageIO.h"

 using namespace cv;


 ERROR_NUMBER CWebImageIO::WriteColourImageToPNGFile(BytePlane bytePlane,  BYTE *bpOutputImage,
         TCHAR *outputFileName)
 {
     int            iNumBands=3;
     int row, col, inputInc, inc;
     BytePlane   bpBufferPlane;

     // Make real colour output plane
     bpBufferPlane=MakeBytePlane(bytePlane.iRows, iNumBands*bytePlane.iColumns, NULL);
     if (!(bpBufferPlane.Data))
         return ERROR_MEMORY_ALLOCATION;

     // Fill buffer plane with test values
     cv::Mat outputImage=cv::Mat(bytePlane.iRows, bytePlane.iColumns, CV_8UC3);
     if (!(outputImage.data))
     {
         FreeBytePlane(bpBufferPlane);
         return ERROR_MEMORY_ALLOCATION;
     }

     memcpy((void *)(outputImage.data), (void *)(bpOutputImage),
             bytePlane.iRows*bytePlane.iColumns*3);

     if (!(imwrite((char *)outputFileName, outputImage)))
     {
         free(bpOutputImage);
         return ErrorWritingFile(outputFileName);
     }

     // Cleanup
     FreeBytePlane(bpBufferPlane);

     return ERROR_NONE;
 }
```

I then try to build it with the following.

```
 g++ `pkg-config opencv --libs` -o dist/Debug/GNU-Linux/progName build/Debug/GNU-Linux/_ext/73c876dd/WebImageIO.o build/Debug/GNU-Linux/main.o /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_calib3d.so -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_contrib -lopencv_core -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_flann -lopencv_gpu -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_legacy -lopencv_ml -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_ocl -lopencv_photo -lopencv_stitching -lopencv_superres -lopencv_ts -lopencv_video -lopencv_videostab -lpng
```

I get the following error message.

```
/home/peter/NetBeansProjects/ApplyModelToSet/../../DraculaFiles/CWebImageIO.cpp:247: undefined reference to `cv::imwrite(cv::String const&, cv::_InputArray const&, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > const&)'
```

I have read that cv::imread (at least) uses the imgcodecs library but

```
 sudo find / -name '*imgcodecs*.so' -print
```

returns no results after my having installed opencv 3.2 on my system

EDIT:

```
pkg-config opencv --libs
```

returns

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_calib3d.so -lopencv_calib3d /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_contrib.so -lopencv_contrib /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_core.so -lopencv_core /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_features2d.so -lopencv_features2d /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_flann.so -lopencv_flann /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_gpu.so -lopencv_gpu /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_highgui.so -lopencv_highgui /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_imgproc.so -lopencv_imgproc /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_legacy.so -lopencv_legacy /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_ml.so -lopencv_ml /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_objdetect.so -lopencv_objdetect /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_ocl.so -lopencv_ocl /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_photo.so -lopencv_photo /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_stitching.so -lopencv_stitching /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_superres.so -lopencv_superres /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_ts.so -lopencv_ts /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_video.so -lopencv_video /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_videostab.so -lopencv_videostab
```

Comment: When you run the `find` command I'm assuming the `*imgcodecs*.so` is actually in single quotes?  What is the output from "pkg-config opencv --libs" when run from the command line?

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  The output was too long for a comment so I added it to the question as an edit.  Thanks,